# gitlab build image generator

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I want to be able to easily create gitlab build images

I heard about a project to easily generate build image to be use in gitlab CI.
No way to find this project, any chance one of you tried it or heard about it ?

Comment: Which type of project/configuration? What technology? For most development ecosystems you can find existing build images.

Comment: The idea is to be able to generate ci images for java project as well as for node or even go. all of them already exist but I'd like to get a tool that would generate  images simply, let's dream about like the https://start.spring.io/ just select what you need and generate

Comment: first google hit? [Build docker images using gitlab-ci](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)

Comment: Pre-bundling packages with build images seems weird, because the whole point in using package managers is to deffer the source elsewhere. If you have static dependencies just link them in the source (Git LFS for example). Regardless, creating build images with docker ( or any container format ) is very easy and straight forward. In docker you can use multi stage builds, And https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#before-multi-stage-builds actually has a 10 liner example go build. Similar base images exist for node & various java ports.